how to enable RouterBuilder schema validation in vertx 4.5.10?
I use RouterBuilder.create(vertx, "openapi.yaml") and with vertx 4.5.10, and I realised, I can get request json fields in my handler, I didn't defined in openapi.yaml.
How can I configure RouterBuilder to not allow, or at least filter out fields, not defined in my openapi.yaml?

you can use the additionalProperties: false property in your openapi.yaml:
content:
  application/json:
    schema:
      type: object
      properties:
        username:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
      additionalProperties: false

